# Adding Optional parameter in ClassLibrary Does not Provide BackWord Compatibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, backwards-compatibility, class-library

I am adding Optional Parameter in My ClassLibrary

Example

```
public static string GetData(string name, string surname, bool status = false){}
```

And My ASPX page is calling method

```
GetData(string name, string surname)
```

I just rebuilt ClassLibrary And Not the ASP page. Then It threw error **Method Not Found**

Please help 
how to maintain backward compatibility? means if i replce just classlibrary then it should not affect my ASP page. I ma using .NET version 4

Thank you

Comment: Create an overload with the additional parameter rather than using an optional parameter.

Comment: This question has the answer as to WHY this isn't working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516256/is-using-optional-parameters-for-backwards-compatibility-a-good-idea?rq=1

Comment: @AsheraH : I read the above comment but did not get that why is it making problem and how to overcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want binary compatibility then yes, you can't add even an optional parameter. What you *can* do is add an overload:

Before:

```
public static string GetData(string name, string surname)
{
    // Real code
}
```

After:

```
public static string GetData(string name, string surname)
{
    return GetData(name, surname, false);
}

public static string GetData(string name, string surname, bool status)
{
    // Real code
}
```

Note that you *could* make `status` optional, but there wouldn't be much point, as any callers not providing an argument would end up calling the two-parameter version. If you were adding more than one parameter though, it would make more sense.

You may well want to consider whether you could live with "rebuilding compatibility", i.e. "all is okay if I rebuild". Strict backward compatibility can be very restrictive - these days *just* dropping a new binary into a built application is relatively rare compared with picking up a new package version when building.